# How do I get the original design back?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, reboot

I have no idea how to describe my problem and no idea why it happened. I just rebooted and for whatever reason my desktop changed. I'm extremely new to Linux (less than 2 weeks total) so just keep that in mind while responding please. I heard it might be an issue with Gnome? It's not just my desktop either, everything looks different. It feels like an entirely different distro.

What my desktop looks like before I rebooted (picture off of Google): [image: What my desktop looked like before I rebooted]

What my desktop looks like after I rebooted: [image: What my desktop looks like after I rebooted]

[EDIT]
I've been using Ubuntu 17.10 with no problems for the past couple of weeks. It's the only OS installed on my system; I am not booting from a USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to "fix" this is to just switch your desktop. Somehow I must have accidentally switched a different desktop (which I didn't even know you could do).

To fix this, logout, and look for some sort of settings in the login screen and select "Ubuntu" when you see it. Mine was set to Cinnamon.

The location of the settings for me was to select my user, then hit the settings icon and select Ubuntu. Yours may be different, but I found this after stumbling upon this article: https://www.howtogeek.com/193129/how-to-install-and-use-another-desktop-environment-on-linux/

Comment: Cinnamon is not installed by default. You installed another DE (Cinnamon). You can also uninstall the other DE.

Comment: I don't know how I would've done that on accident.